# Excel SpecialCells

Tags: excel, vba

101 class for me.  Attempting to count colors in a Pivot table.  Down below is counting all colors including the ones filtered out.

Is there a way to only count the rows being displayed?

This method is not working:

```
For Each TCell In CountRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Problem:  The filtered out rows for that heading are being counted.

```
    Function CountByColor(CellColor As Range, CountRange As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    Dim ICol As Integer
    Dim TCell As Range
    ICol = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
    For Each TCell In CountRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 
       If ICol = TCell.Interior.ColorIndex Then
         CountByColor = CountByColor + 1
       End If
    Next TCell
   End Function
```

Comment: Can you confirm this works as expected on an ordinary worksheet? In other words, the problem is only with pivot tables?

Comment: AFAIK, You can't use `SpecialCells` in a `UserDefinedFunction`. You will have to loop through the cells and check if the row is visible as @Ambie showed you.

Comment: David, i had an earlier problem with Pivot tables conditional formats.  I placed my comments in the reply to Ambie.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of `SpecialCells` as there are some updating difficulties with them. As a result, I go *old school* when it comes to testing for hidden rows, as in the code below:

```
Function CountByColor(CellColor As Range, CountRange As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    Dim ICol As Integer
    Dim TCell As Range
    ICol = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
    For Each TCell In CountRange.Cells
        If Not TCell.EntireRow.Hidden And ICol = TCell.Interior.ColorIndex Then
            CountByColor = CountByColor + 1
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: My earlier problem of having conditional formatting was solved by using "value".  ICol = CellColor.Value.  Ambie, I modifed lines in your code by adding "ICol = CellColor.Value" and the "And ICol = TCell.Value Then.."  My posted problem was not resolved.  It is still counting hidden rows.

Comment: Can you post an exact paste of your `If` line for me to look at please?

Comment: Yes, Ambie.         
      If Not TCell.EntireRow.Hidden And ICol = TCell.CellColor.Value Then
            CountByColor = CountByColor + 1

Comment: Correction because the other way with ".CellColor.Value" give errors:   If Not TCell.EntireRow.Hidden And ICol = TCell.Value Then
            CountByColor = CountByColor + 1

Comment: Okay, split that `If` clause into two and see if it'll recognize a hidden row. `If Not TCell.EntireRow.Hidden Then` | `If ICol = TCell.Value Then`

Comment: Again, 101 for me.  I add 2 If clauses and got a compiler error.  *For      Each TCell In CountRange.Cells
        If Not TCell.EntireRow.Hidden And If ICol = TCell.Value Then
            CountByColor = CountByColor + 1
    End If*
Next TCell

Comment: Yes, that second `If` clause is the wrong syntax. We can help you with that later. For now, let's just sort out the hidden row issue. So delete the second `If` clause entirely and see if it'll break on a hidden row.

Comment: Ambie, I did a test on a small number of all of the colors.  It works on Green, Red and the other colors that have values.  When I filter out some of the colors with values the count is correct.  It is the "no value" checks that is causing the problem with the code you gave me.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I placed the function with a range all the way to the bottom with a lot of empty blank boxes.  It was picking up the empty blank boxes.  I just need to set the range just right.